# Relation between infinitesimals in Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Given is a function $f(E)$. If $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and thus $dv=\frac{dE}{mv}$, then the following Riemann sums are equal to each other. For simplicity's sake the intervals are considered equal so that:
$$\lim_{\Delta E\rightarrow0}\sum_{n=\frac{a}{\Delta E}}^{\frac{b}{\Delta E}-1}f(n\cdot \Delta E)\Delta E=\lim_{\Delta v\rightarrow0}\sum_{n={\sqrt{\frac{2a}{m}\cdot}\frac{1}{\Delta v}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{2b}{m}}\cdot \frac{1}{\Delta v}-1}f(n\cdot \Delta v)\cdot mv\cdot \Delta v$$
I noticed that even if $\Delta E$ and $\Delta v$ are *numerically infinitesimally equal*, this equation still holds. So the relation $dv=\frac{dE}{mv}$ doesn't need to be taken into account for Rieman sums, as long as the intervals $\Delta E$ and $\Delta v$ approach $0$.

If the above premise is correct, then a confusion arises when writing these sums as integrals and taking one step of the integration:
$$f(E)dE=f(v)mvdv$$
This equation shows that $dv$ *must* be equal to $\frac{dE}{mv}$ otherwise the equation is invalid. This also makes sense to me because a step in $dE$ equals a step $\frac{dE}{mv}$ in $v$ dimensions.

So how can the relation $dv=\frac{dE}{mv}$ be ignored when summed/integrated but must hold when looking at one step of the sum/integration? Is my premise wrong in the first place?

Comment: Sorry I don't get this. By the change of variable formula,
$$
\int_A^Bf(E)\,dE=\int_{\sqrt{2A/m}}^{\sqrt{2B/m}}f\Big(\frac{mv^2}{2}\Big)\,mv\,dv
$$
which we can discretize if we want. Where have we ignored the relation $E=\frac{mv^2}{2}$ or, what is the same, $dE=mv\,dv$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. When looking specifically at $dE$ and $dv$ of these integrations, these values don't need to be adjusted during the integration based on the relationship $dE=mvdv$. Both $dE$ and $dv$ can be even considered numerically infinitesimally equal, and yet the integrals give the same outcome. For example, the integration.. $$\int_A^Bf(E)dE$$ ..does not need to "know" that $dE$ must change by size according to $\sqrt{2mE}dv$ for each integration step. It can be unrelatedly infinitesimally small and it will still equal the other integration in terms of $v$.

Comment: It is true that the $dE$ integral doesn't need to know anything about $v$. I disagree however that $dE$ and $dv$ can be considered to be equal - even when a numerical experiment gives that impression. (There are many MSE posts discussing infinitesimals and how they differ from real numbers.) What were the exact parameters in your numerical experiment ?

Comment: @KurtG. I have chosen $f(E)=E^2$ and $dv$ and $dE$ both to be 0.0001 for example. The Riemann sums will approach the same outcome. If $dE$ and $dv$ must always differ a factor $mv$, why is it explained that for Riemann sums any interval may approach $0$ regardless of their inner relationship with each other? The separate integrations also don't know their inner relationship. 

Perhaps one can ignore their relationship when they are summed/integrated because their difference is negligible but when looking at an individual step the difference would become noticeable?

Comment: In the discretization of the $dE$ integral you can surely use $\Delta E=0.0001$ and you can use $\Delta v=0.0001$ in the discretization of the $dv$ integral. The observation that this gives numerically close (therefore "correct") results *does not* imply mathematically that $dE=mv\,dv$ is suddenly wrong. I begin to think where you are coming from. That whole line of reasoning sounds absurd to me.

Comment: @KurtG. I didn't mean to say $dE=mvdv$ is wrong, but according to the Riemann sums which states that an interval approaching $0$ leads to a limit + the fact that this limit coincides whether it's in terms of $dE$ or $dv$, makes me think that their relation becomes negligible when summing/integrating. Mind you, the $mv$ parameter in the integrand $f(v)mv$ is exactly necessary for equality to hold, but I'm specifically talking about $dE$ and $dv$ not needing to adjust during summation/integration. Is my "negliglibilty" reasoning of their relationship when summing/integrating still incorrect?

Comment: I cannot follow hocus pocus. One thing I noticed is that you wrote $f(E)\,dE=\color{red}{f}(v)mv\,dv$ . The second $f$ should either be another function (now of $v$) or you should replace $f(E)$ by $f(mv^2/2)$. Riemann integration and change of variables in hundrets of years old. I am dropping out.

Comment: @KurtG. I can't follow hocus pocus either, hence my question in the first place how separate Riemann sums/integrals give the same outcome while both intervals approach $0$.

Comment: I am running out of ideas to explain this. One last attempt: Integrate the constant function $f\equiv 1$ over $dE$ from $A$ to $B$. When I get you right you believe this should be the same as Riemann approximating $\int dv$ (with transformed limits) instead of $\int mv\,dv$ . You will notice that $\int dv$ gives an obviously wrong result.

Comment: @KurtG. You misunderstood, I didn't say that. In your example $$\int dE = \int mvdv$$ both $dE$ and $dv$ may approach $0$ to the same extent (based on the Riemann sums) and the integrations are still equal. While looking at a single step $$dE=mvdv$$ Either $dE$ or $dv$ must change to give the other, since $mv$ changes with each step.

Comment: I see. And what is wrong with this? When we  let the Riemann sums converge we can choose the sequence of step sizes at will. As long as they approach zero the right integral will come out. Implicitly I said this in my very first comment  already.

Comment: @KurtG. But that's the confusion I'm talking about. The separate Riemann sums state that for each step, $dE$ and $dv$ can be considered approaching 0, to the same extent "at will". 
But $dE=mvdv$ states that for each summation/integration step, $dE$ and $dv$ must differ a factor $mv$. E.g., the first step of the integration of mvdv should therefore equal the first step of the separate integration of dE. Either $dv$ or $dE$ should be adjusted accordingly. But that's not what the Riemann sums require.This is the confusion.

Comment: Last attempt (I ***promise***) : The individual summands in the Riemann sum for the $dE$ integral do not have to be equal to the individual summands in the Riemann sum for the $dv$ integral. That's why you can choose $\Delta E=\Delta v= 0.0001$ and get a "correct" numerical result. Do you notice that I write $\Delta E$ and not $dE$ ? ***When and only when*** you want to prove the change of variable formula you worry about $dE=mv\,dv$. This shows you what extra factor $mv$ you have to put into the integral that you can later discretize "at will" with $mv\Delta v$.

Comment: @KurtG. This is the answer that addressed my confusion. Thank you.